# EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGILL) Crash while using Autolayout?

Tags: ios, crash, autolayout, exc-bad-access

This crash only happened on iOS 10.2.1, others devices or simulators are fine. Because I don't have iOS 10.2.1 device or simulator, there is no way to reproduce.

Here is [Crash Log](https://github.com/hi-guy/iOSCrashLog/blob/master/crashLog.md) (Github link).

What I did was fetch data from server and `reloadData` by `UITableView`. Crashed while `reloadData`. All of operation are in main queue block.

Some code in `UITableViewCell` as below:

```
- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    if (self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {

        [self.contentView addSubview:self.avatarImageView];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.messageBackgroundView];
        [self.messageBackgroundView addSubview:self.messageTextView];
    }
    return self;
}

+ (BOOL)requiresConstraintBasedLayout {
    return YES;
}

- (void)prepareForReuse {
    [super prepareForReuse];

    [self.messageBackgroundView mas_remakeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {

    }];
}

- (void)updateConstraints {

    [self.avatarImageView mas_remakeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {

        make.size.mas_equalTo(CGSizeMake(38, 38));
        make.top.equalTo(self.contentView.mas_top).offset(9).priorityHigh();
        if (self.myself) {
            make.trailing.equalTo(self.contentView.mas_trailing).offset(-18);
        } else {
            make.leading.equalTo(self.contentView.mas_leading).offset(18);
        }

    }];

    [self.messageBackgroundView mas_remakeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {

        if (self.myself) {
            make.trailing.equalTo(self.avatarImageView.mas_leading).offset(-9);
            make.leading.mas_greaterThanOrEqualTo(self.contentView.mas_leading).offset(44);
        } else {
            make.leading.equalTo(self.avatarImageView.mas_trailing).offset(9);
            make.trailing.mas_lessThanOrEqualTo(self.contentView.mas_trailing).offset(-44);
        }

        make.top.equalTo(self.avatarImageView.mas_top);
        make.bottom.equalTo(self.contentView.mas_bottom).offset(-9).priorityHigh();
    }];

    [self.messageTextView mas_updateConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.edges.equalTo(self.messageBackgroundView).insets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(8, 14, 8, 14));
        make.height.equalTo(@(self.textViewHeight));
    }];

    [super updateConstraints];
}

- (void)setMessage:(GWBaseModel *)message {

    _message = message;

    // ... update ui, set height for textview

    [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints];

}
```

Comment: Please add the crash log here to understand the issue better.

Comment: @Swati The content of log is so long that cannot put all here. The github link in the description might give a better preview.

Comment: Can you try adding reloadData between beginupdates and endupdates?

Comment: @Swati Thank you, but it doesn't work. Tester told me that still happend. it only happened on iOS 10.2.1, this bugs me. Is there anything special in iOS 10.2.1? After Checked iOS Release Notes I got nothing.